# I am not able to plug in force.com IDE in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to plug in force.com IDE in Eclipse. i am trying to plug in using this link **http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42** But it firing an error like

**Unable to connect to repository http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/content.xml

can anybody give me updated link or related suggestions.

Comment: Please check this link:------
http://en.savefrom.net/#url=http://youtube.com/watch?v=0e0hGId1aPM&utm_source=youtube.com&utm_medium=short_domains&utm_campaign=ssyoutube.com

Comment: how you solve this?I directly paste http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/content.xml and it give access denied.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried steps 1, 2 and 3 of the instructions in [Force.com IDE Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) and the "Force.com IDE" was listed. So the repository could be connected to.

I suggest you try again having confirmed that your network is working.